# slow boot time on two static IPs

Tags: boot, networking, ethernet, interface

I was wondering why I have such a slow boot time when I have two static IPs set in the `/etc/networ/interfaces` file?

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.8.10.8
netmask 255.255.0.0
gateway 10.8.1.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 169.254.1.1
netmask 255.255.0.0
```

If I remove `eth1` IP settings then the boot time is normal speed.  When they are in there like the above example then I get stuck in a black screen with a blinking cursor in the top left.  It then proceeds to do that for a minute or two until it finally boots into the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the `/etc/init/failsafe.conf` file was holding up the boot time.  In ym `/var/log/syslog` a message popped up saying `failsafe: Failsafe of 120 seconds reached` which lead me to looking into this file.  I am assuming since both IPs are being set to static the network configuration is taking longer to setup due to this.  I am however not 100% sure about this reasoning.  Any explanation would be nice to why it had to wait the full 120 seconds.